# How can a question have more downvotes than views?

Tags: discussion, support, views

Six views, seven votes:

[image]

Link to the original question:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49166/exactly-has-been-bred-11s

(but it may be changed or deleted by the time you access it)

NOTE: This question is about downvotes, NOT upvotes.

Comment: you need to refresh page to update `Viewed`.

Comment: I don't need to refresh anything if I am viewing the page for the first time (as it was the case). Also, I did not vote.

Comment: If it was an answer it could have been merged into the question, although that obviously isn't an option for a question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on MSE?

Comment: I think I've seen vote counts being refreshed automatically (via AJAX) without having to reload the page. I'm not sure the views count is updated in the same way.

Comment: @AndrewMedico It's perfectly fine to ask questions like this on local per-site metas.

Comment: @AnnaLear My confusion is that the referenced question is from Mathematica.SE and this is Meta StackOverflow.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Oh, *that* MSE. Good lord, we have too many identical acronyms. My bad.

Comment: @nicael, this doesn't look like a duplicate, since the cause of the problem on this similar question was apparently a bug related to the migration. No migration involved here, it seems.

Answer (score 63):

There could be more downvotes than views if users downvoted *and* cast spam flags on the question. Spam or offensive flags cast an additional downvote from the system immediately, but are removed if the flag is declined.

For more information about how spam flags work, see [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Plus there's caching of the views count but not of the votes.

Comment: Really? This may explain the case. Since the question was really a spam, and it is probable that several people flagged it, on top of downvoting.

Comment: Also the votes are updated in real-time via JavaScript.

Answer (score 14):

As well as the spam flag autodownvote Quantas mentioned, the question could have been in a review queue. I don't think seeing a question in a review queue counts as a view, but in some queues you can still vote.

That is probably not the case in this particular example, but it *is* a way a question can have more votes than views.

Comment: @Joe I know for certain that you can vote in FP and LA.

Comment: Oh, those would be 'action's wouldn't they.