# Educating people to flag spam and not vote to close

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, spam

**TL DR**

Is there anything we can do to help educate users to use their flags and not their close votes on spam?

---

It is not uncommon to see people voting to close spam. Spam should be flagged as spam and then it will be deleted when there are sufficient spam flags on the post. [Between 15 and 20% of all posts that were flagged as spam also have at least 1 close vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327733/3956566).

This is one of the latest examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278819/high-dh-simply-means-rapid-and-better-absorption

[image]

There is no point voting to close them,

- You need 5 close votes (and several K in rep) to close a question and
- Then 3 delete votes (and 10 k in rep) to delete it and this takes time.
- Spam is able to be deleted with 6 spam flags
- The people who vote to close are likely not using their spam flags, so it takes longer to delete
- Also the close vote queue is huge and many people wouldn't want to waste their votes on spam
- Users get spam flags sooner than close vote privileges  (at only 15 rep).
- Flagging it as spam puts an instant block on the account; voting to delete doesn't
- [A spam flag casts an automatic downvote on the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258456/3956566), which is removed if the flag is declined

[From the words](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263054/3956566) of [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)

> The best way to make spam ineffective is to delete it quickly! The single best thing you can do when you see spam is flag it .../
>
> /... Just about anything else you can do is at best a waste of your time and effort, unless it somehow leads directly to more folks flagging the post as spam.

---

Latest incident (two close votes)

[image]

Comment: @RyanBemrose *Don't feed the trolls!* Spam should get as less attention as possible. So we should just flag it and move on. Voting to close just gives them more attention.

Comment: As a side note, it is always better to "delete the post by flagging it as spam" instead of voting to delete. The former puts an instant block on the account. The latter doesn't. So, unless people want to see more spam posts from the same account, spam flag is the way to go.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317277/show-a-warning-when-someone-uses-a-custom-close-reason-containing-the-word-spam).

Comment: See my also less explicit call to action  [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268201/should-the-spam-handling-guidance-be-consolidated-into-a-single-post) on  MSE?

Comment: This is not a duplicate http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317277/show-a-warning-when-someone-uses-a-custom-close-reason-containing-the-word-spam, That question asks for a specific feature, I am asking how we can educate users.

Comment: Hmm, you just don't know.  This could well be a highly responsible SO user that used a CV *and* flagged the post.  One doesn't preclude the other.  Slightly more concerning is that the question still wasn't removed after 7 DVs.

Comment: @HansPassant the linked spam question had 7 delete votes on it?

Comment: DV == downvote.

Comment: @HansPassant it ended up with 12 downvotes and took 10 mins to delete, so all those people who downvoted could've flagged as spam. I know it's not that important, it's just it seems to reveal that people don't realise they can flag as spam also.

Comment: 12 downvotes is two per spam flagger: one normal and one from the flag, so that adds up.

Comment: @JoshCaswell spam flags give automatic downvotes?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes you're right http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258456/3956566 I never knew that, thanks

Comment: What are the *cv-query-pls* and *cv-pls* links that are at the right of the *close (1)* link? Is it an extension?

Comment: @Zanon https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts

Comment: @Zanon the cv-query-pls is one I mocked up from another user's cv-pls and I'm thinking of changing the name, it's to post into the [socvr](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to ask if people think it's off topic, the cv-pls is to ask for close votes on a question that's off topic and getting answers, or attention that may lead to answers. 'report' will post a report to smoke detector in [charcoal hq](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) hence my interest in the spam, I see a lot of it. All scripts

Comment: Marking as spam is like living in the wild west. There is no indication given if others are flagging same also. I usually do both for that reason.

Comment: Might be good to rename the "flag" link as "spam" so people know what its for.

Comment: @JohnAment it is also for abuse and other things.

Comment: stackexchange should use [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) algorithm to determine if the question is related to the topic of the domain or not. automatically elimination of such posts is best course of action to keep the infinite and rising flow of spam. I worked in a place years ago which did such text analysis with strong results and am sure than after 6 years this can clean up with more than 80% accuracy.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Yes, spam should be flagged to death as quickly as possible. Does it hurt if it also picks up some close-votes? In what measurable way?

Comment: I'd be curious to get the stats after this has been finished featuring to see if there are less close votes on spam.

Comment: +1 for the first comment on that latest incident ... ;)

Comment: Captain Obvious here . . . I've only been posting for a while and don't see a "spam" link only a "flag" link. If the spam link were more obvious, more people would use it. Maybe have a link that says "spam". Flag could mean nearly anything. (assuming I'm guessing correctly and flag is actually "flag as spam")

Comment: The reason this happens is because we've been told that once you get close votes, *you're supposed to stop flagging stuff to close* and instead use your close vote.  So all those people that used to flag stuff rarely use the flag link anymore, so on the rare occasion a spam post makes it into their feed, they're going to do what they always do, use their close votes.

Comment: Same goes for flagging nonsense questions that are abusive of the sites resources http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771425

Comment: Any spam post is exceedingly likely to be removed through spam flags _long_ before it has time to gather 5 close votes and 3 delete votes. What does it matter if one or two close votes get spent? I haven't seen any actual data indicating that this is a real problem.

Comment: @NisseEngström yes exactly, meaning the people voting to close are acting in good faith and completely wasting their time. Isn't it better that their actions count towards something, rather than them doing something that is pointless? It is not a huge problem, it is a simple misalignment in how to use the site.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

### How to educate people

Things the common user can do:

- Posting this meta question is how you educated me. Other people not marking this as a duplicate (even though it seems pretty similar to previous questions) will keep it in the Hot Meta Posts pool for the full three days, thus maximizing exposure. This can't be done too often, though. Most of the time, the next point is enough.
- Leaving a comment like you did that tells other people to flag it as spam is also a good practice. If I regularly saw that kind of comment after a spam post I would get the idea.

Things that would take more than the common user to implement:

- Make this question or a similar blog post a featured topic for a week. From time to time bring this and other important topics back to the sidebar to educate new users. I don't read old meta posts but I do read the things that appear in the sidebar.
- I like the ideas about having a "report spam" link or a "spam" option in the close vote dialog. However, I'm not sure if this happens often enough to warrant the extra UI space it would take. See [Can we trial a line in the close vote reasons other with a link to flag as spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327711/can-we-trial-a-line-in-the-close-vote-reasons-other-with-a-link-to-flag-as-spam) for the discussion on this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you make some very good points  and part of the reason I posted this question and got it reopened, was I knew it would  educate people :) , but as you say it's only a once off, it would be good if the se team or mods could pin a feature question for the week.

Comment: It also makes sense to have a comprehensive list of well known spam links for reference in case someone is not sure if a link is spam or not. In my experience there are many common spam links (long path tool, for example) but only a few people know about them and the rest mark such spam posts as "VLQ / NAA" instead of spam.

Comment: @TheLostMind in that case - we'd be better off pushing such posts straight into the spam queue for review - listing what's being looked out for will just give spammers a hint on workarounds...

Comment: @JonClements - Thats true. My argument was based on the fact that initially I didn't know "long path tool" posts were spam, I remember marking them as VLQ / NAA a couple of times. . I believe if we have a list of words (not exact matches) for example "long path tool", "ONLINE SAP TRAINING at XYZ.com", then people might consider them as spam (which is right) and not VLQ / NAA (and push them to that queue). A spam post like the latter needs to have atleast "SAP", <xyz.com> and "training" (or synonyms of those) in that post. And if people look at the list they can find out that that's the case.

Comment: @TheLostMind true there will be cases where people don't realise it's spam straight off, which is a little different to voting to close something you think is spam.

Comment: @JonClements if we get enough support for some of these answers, I think it would be good to plan a feature-request to implement them, what do you think? e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327682/3956566

Comment: For additional educational value you could also combine the two points and post a comment "flag as spam because ..." with a link to this question.

Answer (score 260):

Really close to what others have proposed already, but how about adding a message telling people to flag the post if it is spam inside the vote-to-close popup?[image: Message "If this is spam, click here to flag this instead" inside vote to close popup.]

Comment: yes I believe this is a good solution and should not be difficult to implement if the community wants it.

Comment: I think if this gets enough upvotes, this would be a good feature request. It is less intrusive than this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317277/show-a-warning-when-someone-uses-a-custom-close-reason-containing-the-word-spam and with little development time.

Comment: This feels like killing a fly with a jackhammer. I can't imagine how many more bad spam flags we'd get, for questionable benefit.

Comment: @undo the middle ground is to a dd this warning if the answer has a spam flag (or 2)

Comment: @Undo that is a good point, I didn't think of that. Maybe we could trial it, if the team is ok with that, the development cost would be low I imagine.

Comment: @Yvette I'm still not convinced that this is really a *problem*, especially on Stack Overflow. What harm is it causing?

Comment: @psubsee2003 or to add it to the off topic/  other custom reason of the close vote dialog.

Comment: @Undo it's just educating users on how to user the tools as intended and the gap here that there are people with 40 k rep who didn't know this. Harm, well it might keep spam on the site a little longer, if that constitutes harm.

Comment: A feature request along these lines http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327711/can-we-trial-a-line-in-the-close-vote-reasons-other-with-a-link-to-flag-as-spam

Comment: Just add spam as a close reason and convert it to a flag automatically, imo.

Comment: Alternate version with an additional option for spam: http://i.stack.imgur.com/icH31.png

Comment: Maybe get rid of "flags" as a separate selection and build them into downvoting. If you want to flag as spam or mark to close, you must first downvote. The downvote dialog will ask why you're downvoting and that selection may result in a flag.

Comment: What about only showing that warning if the question has at least one spam flag?  We could also show a warning if there is a comment containing "spam" or if the user votes to close with a custom reason containing "spam."

Answer (score 56):

One practical way would be to have an ***"Is it Spam?"*** option right inside the Close link.

So that even if a user starts out wrong by selecting "Close" when he ought to have used "Flag" you can still later gently nudge him down the right path?

Comment: I like this idea, and gave you a upvote, however it will be redundant for the majority of close votes, so may be superfluous. Might be better when the user clicks on the custom reason when close voting.

Comment: It seems that user2428118 just duplicated your idea with a very large picture.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yes, I noticed that. Ah well, what can I do. It's good StackExchange points don't have monetary value else I'd have been so pissed. :)

Comment: @ThomasKilian Just for fun I edited my answer. It takes a copycat to styme a copycat. :p

Comment: SO is not a place where justness is in first place. Well, lessons to learn ;-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian Indeed. So long as one doesn't take the reputation points too seriously it is all fun. :)

Comment: I rolled back the edit that copied the image from @user2428118. Although the idea was first yours, the image that made the idea clear was first from that user. It is too confusing having the same image in both answers. Also, no rep points are gained or lost in meta discussion.

Comment: @Suragch Fair enough. It was only a joke. I wasn't doing it for the points.

Answer (score 28):

As long as users need to be specifically 'educated' to do this correctly, there seems to be something wrong with the interface. You cannot expect to get good coverage on stopping 'offending' methods by teaching, as in these posts for instance.

Several visual or technical solutions come to mind and have been proposed in other answers, but the point I'm trying to make is that if this is critical enough that we want to do something about it, 'education' is probably not the most effective?

- We could add a close-reason ('spam') that has the same effect as a flag? This is a sneaky one, but if people want to close, why not let them, and take away the bad things closing does? This is a great option as far as i'm conserned: no extra UI space, everyone goes on doing what they want, but now it isn't ill-advised anymore.
- Add some sort of "this is spam" button. Not sure I like that, it adds to the options that you already have.

Comment: yes, this is interesting point, but doesn't really solve the issue, maybe changing 'flag' to 'report' is a better option. I like the input thanks.

Comment: Well, if people keep on voting to close, and this makes a problem because of the reasons you mentioned above, and you make that close-vote behave as a flag... then why isn't the problem solved?

Comment: I think if it was added in red to the voting to close as other reason it could work.

Comment: Probably because the official line is that once you get enough rep to do close votes, *you're supposed to stop flagging things* and instead use your close vote instead.  After being trained to use close votes, I hardly ever use flags at all.

Comment: Why not add a link like other answers have specified? The 'spam' button you suggest cannot be added, there are alerady 7 buttons max on the bottom line of a question (if you're a mod, AFAIK). 8th button? NO!

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps it is only me, but perhaps the word 'flag' is not that self evident. If you take Gmail, they have '**report spam**' which cannot be mistaken. I don't know if it possible with the stackexchange system to run A/B tests to see if a change in wording would make a difference.

Comment: This is speculation at best. Other [corners](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091115170732AAljsoI) of the internet [seem to use the word](http://techin.oureverydaylife.com/mean-flag-something-facebook-3079.html) with [more or less](https://teamsideline.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201151007-What-does-the-red-flag-mean-next-to-an-email-address-) the same meaning. Without further research, there's no way to tell either way.

Comment: Yes, it's speculation. But also your 'corners' link somehow gives some prove that 'flag' does not have a very clear meaning in comparision to 'report spam' - or 'close' for that matter.

Comment: Anyone who has close vote privileges has no business being completely unaware of how SO spam handling works, or the flag link for that matter.

Comment: @Laurel one of your links actually proves Ridcully's point facebook uses report (not flag)

Comment: Not everyone who has close vote privileges is active in moderating the site, but will act on spam when they see it. @NathanTuggy I've had high rep users comment when I've mentioned to flag as spam, and also Suragch didn't know and s/he's 40k. It's not unusual.

Comment: @Yvette: I can (sort of) understand being a little confused about which is optimal. I can't understand someone with 3k not even knowing, in a vague sort of way, that there *is* a flag option, or a spam choice within that. (Which is what this answer assumes.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've had several people comment to me that they had no idea that they were supposed to flag as spam and cast close votes, and that's just people I've bumped into on the site. So rather than think, well they **should** know about it, apparently some people don't, so this is one way of letting them know. Not everybody is as active  on or interested in meta and we can't penalise then for that really, just get the word out.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: You seem to think reputation correlates with experience with all of the site's features. That is not the case. This is yet another example of an entirely rep-based privilege system being flawed to the core. You don't learn about *moderation* by earning reputation through doing *things that have nothing to do with moderation*.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** Allow the user to tell the system what's wrong and let the system decide which action to take. Don't concern the user with that choice.

---

Right now the process goes like this:

1. Notice that something is wrong
2. Try to remember, research, guess, or infer from failure which action you're supposed to perform for this issue: vote to close, delete, flag, etc (or quit)
3. Open a dialog for that action (if you can)
4. Pick a reason why that action applies (if it's there... or go back to step 2, or quit)
5. Submit

... which actually seems a little backwards. Step 2 seems like a huge liability. Why do we even need it? The user shouldn't have to choose which action to take. They should merely be reporting what's wrong so that the system can take the appropriate action on their behalf:

1. Notice that something is wrong
2. Open a "something's wrong" dialog
3. Explain what's wrong (multiple checkboxes: it's a dupe, looks like an ad, etc)
4. Submit, letting the system determine and take the appropriate action, e.g.: close, delete, flag, etc.

The idea is that the UI for raising issues would offer no distinction between flag, close, or delete. Based on the problems described by the user, the system would prioritize action and route things to the appropriate queue. If the appropriate action would be to close, and the user can't yet vote to close, perhaps just thank them for their feedback and log the attempt anyway. Same thing if they're out of votes or flags or whatever. That logging could provide useful information for future discussions on rate limiting and feature metering.

Comment: Yes so have one link to include flags and close votes and the close vote option will only show if the use has privs

Comment: @Yvette The idea is that the UI would offer no distinction between flag, close, or delete. Based on the problem described by the user, the system would route things appropriately. If the appropriate action would be to close, and the user can't yet vote to close, perhaps just thank them for their feedback and log the attempt anyway. Same thing if they're out of votes or flags or whatever. That logging could provide useful information for future discussions on rate limiting and feature metering.

Comment: ah yes, much better idea than current system, thanks for the clarity

Comment: This definitely has potential to eliminate a lot of confusion about moderation on all levels, but I think it would be really hard to design and particularly to label correctly.

Answer (score 7):

As a regular it is easy to vaguely recall seeing a number of posts with issues and assume that we now have a problem.

What is much more difficult is to check the data to verify that there *is* in fact a problem, and use the data to assist in determining an appropriate solution.

**Is there actually a problem here that needs solving?**

Are spam posts that get closed instead of flagged, or closed first and *then* flagged common enough that we need to come up with a solution?

**How can we determine if there's a problem?**

What data should we be looking for to determine that spam isn't getting flagged? What does the data look like currently? What would it look like it the problem were fixed? That way, if and when we determine to implement a solution, we'll be able to tell if the solution actually solves the problem.

---

With all of that said, I think having a "close as spam" close option that is just an alias for "flag as spam" wouldn't hurt. Anyone voting to close questions is going to intuitively know that they want to "close" spam questions, even though that's not actually what happens to spam.

Comment: some more accurate stats http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327733/3956566

Answer (score 4):

My initial train of thought was along the lines of "how can we punish these people". Now, however, I am starting to think that "punishment" is part of the problem.

You have pointed out several different actions that a user may take:

- flag as spam
- down vote
- close vote

Only one of those actions has the possibility to result in "punishment", but that option (flagging as spam) is the correct option. **It's possible that the flag could get declined.**

If a user, in the past, has made some wrong choices and gotten declined flags, they will be less likely to flag in the future. They may also be facing a flag ban, which makes them unable to flag at all.

It's worth wondering if some of this stuff gets flagged as abusive. Or a custom mod flag is used. Custom mod flags might explain a lot.

It's also possible that the user ran out of flags, as I often did early on (before close votes, when I had very much less than 100 flags). That would also make them incapable of flagging.

---

Keep in mind that it's possible that a user may flag as spam, and take another action, such as down voting (likely) or close voting (unlikely). I'm not sure how much harm there is to doing either option **in addition** to flagging as spam.

Comment: I agree that punishment is not viable, these people are voting to close in good faith (I presume) and do not know that they should be flagging instead.  Yes running out of flags is a possibility, though people earn more flags with rep, so is increasingly less likely, plus there is feedback people didn't know they should flag. Also the one's who so use all their flags are more likely to leave a comment to flag as spam and a downvote, than a close vote. You raise some good points though, I only just saw this answer, sorry for missing it earlier.

Comment: Punish?? for what? If doing both is wrong then i am certainly guilty since there is no feedback whatsoever related to x number flags will automatically  close and no counter showing if others are also flagging. Can't punish user for a UI problem. Shouldn't expect users to have to read through all of  Meta either to know better

Comment: @charlietfl You misunderstood what I said. "More punishment" was only one train of thought in my idea generation process. I discarded the idea once I realized how punishment has ironic twists, which is essentially what the rest of the answer is about.

Comment: @charlietfl learning to use the site is like reading a legal test book (but more interesting).

Comment: Closing doesn't remove the spam; deleting doesn't always remove the spam. There needs to be an option not to see posts "deleted as spam".

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the entire closing system is flawed basically. It was flawed originally, and the back-pedaled "on hold" form of it was just a terminology change.

There need be only one comprehensive moderation system which confronts every type of shit there can be, from low quality on-topic posts to outright spam.

This concept of several votes which transition a question to a languishing state in which new answers are not accepted is completely pointless, and leads to the proliferation of low quality posts. In particular, there is an accumulation in StackOverflow of old, low-quality questions which are just one or two votes short of being put on hold. There are thousands and thousands of them.

The ideal way to get people not to use this "on hold" mechanism inappropriately is to consolidate it with the flagging system into a single, sensible moderation mechanism.

If the "on hold" concept must be retained, then, in recognition of the fact that people will use it inappropriately, **spam should be available as one of the close reasons**.

That is to say, when you click the close button, one of the choices should be: **"I'm voting to close this because ... it is spam"**.  When the user selects this, a dialog box can appear which says **"Voting isn't the right mechanism for identifying spam; would you like to flag this posting? **

Similarly, the other flagging choices could be in the voting UI, like "inappropriate", "offensive" and so on.

**When people persist in going through the wrong use case flow in the UI, don't blame the people. Fix the darned UI so it steers stray users to the correct use case!**

Answer (score -2):

The reason is obvious: Close has a lot higher visibility than Spam as Spam is hidden behind the Flag option.

The solution is to promote Spam to a first class citizen or as @User242x suggest put some text on the Close screen.

As an aside I have only ever come across a spam post once and I have to admit I probably clicked close.

Answer (score -2):

## Educating people after the fact

How about educating people by sending them a mail after the fact? (Given that this really is a problem.) In pseudo code:

```
counter = 0
for post in spam_posts:
    if user_voted_to_close(post) and user_flagged_as_spam(post):
        counter += 1

if counter >= 3:
    send_mail(user,
        "Hello, we've detected that your votes are not as effective as they could be.
         Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327636"
    )
```

Even if this does not catch everything (sometimes a question might be closed instead of deleted as spam), I think this catches everyone after a while.

## Alternative

If the data shows that people often flag and close at the same time, we could just disable the close button ("Sorry, you can only either flag or close, prefer flag if unsure.") after flagging a post.

Comment: Or a notification to their inbox might be better. I think this is a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

**You don't educate people. You educate as many people as possible.**

Even in real life, even if 99% of the class get an A, one will fail it.

On a website that has millions of users, there will be few people ignoring the post, others voting to close but what's important is that the vast majority will flag it. If the website has only few hundred users, then yes this would be a problem, but when you have millions of users, seeing 1 or 2 or 3 close votes, it's not even 0.1% of the users.

Besides most of the people who needs education, don't bother visiting meta to read the rules, new posts and get "educated". Come one [this crap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0) which is far crappier than all the spam posts on SE ever still got 591,061 likes as of today, you still want to educate people? judging by numbers, i think SE community is well educated when compared to youtube.

Comment: out of the many users on SO only a portion of these are active in any moderation, including flagging.

Answer (score -5):

## Flag!

Add a link on the close vote screen saying that you need to flag <s>(or vote to delete if you have privs)</s> (always flag) as spam.

## New deletion type!

There *should* be a new type of deletion: **spam**. Also, an option must be then added in the user preferences: View posts deleted as spam [?] (checkbox). This will be able to hide the spam, as it should.

## No close!

There shouldn't be any "spam" close reason.

Comment: There is already a way to delete spam, and that's called flagging as spam.  When a post is deleted as spam or abusive, [it is already censored](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/323179). Furthermore, there is no close as spam reason, unless you use the custom (you type the text) reason.

Comment: @Laurel I don't mean just censor, I mean full hide (just a notice at the top, maybe, to show the hidden posts).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ILXPA.png

Comment: @Laurel I really mean hide, not just censor...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "hide" then...

Comment: @Laurel The answer not show up at all, like if you don't have the priviledge to view deleted posts. Just a notice on the answer bar to be able to show the spam answers. Because spam can be, like, 379 copies of the same answer. Would you want to have 379 spam censors taking up space?