# Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?

Tags: discussion, faq, flags, declined-flags

Every post or comment flag dialog has an option to raise a custom (moderator) flag:

[image: Image of moderator intervention dialog box]

Every day, moderators receive a lot of custom flags that do not need to be custom flags. Custom flags take a longer time to process.

If a custom flag is raised where a standard flag could be used instead, it may be declined.

- When should I use, or refrain from raising, a custom flag?
- What information should I provide when raising a custom flag?

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 75):

I'm going to try to TL;DR [Yvette's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368694/2751851). Note that I'm referring to *post* flags; comment flags are a different story and I mostly don't care about how you flag those:

*Do not* use 'other' flags when it's reasonable to use a standard flag. It will not be handled faster, and there's a decent chance you'll get a decline and start over.

*Do* use 'other' flags when:

- A standard flag *would* suffice, but the situation is non-obvious or otherwise complex. For example:

  - Someone has posted a gazillion NAAs, and you think we might want to message them
  - Spam that looks valid at first glance. We get a bunch of actually-invalid spam flags; 'other' flags get more scrutiny. Explain why you're not using a standard flag.
- Something requires specific attention, and can't reasonably be handled without superpowers.
- A post needs most/all comments purged; an 'other' flag is faster for you and about the same for us as handling a dozen comment flags.

In general, if you acknowledge that you're using an 'other' flag and present a reason, you'll be fine. If you're the eighteenth flag saying only "please close this" today, you're probably getting a decline.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the *there's a decent chance you'll get a decline*. Why is it so bothersome if I say *This comment is no longer needed* in a custom flag? I'm desperate for examples of flags you declined solely for this reason. I'm really into the position: If the flag is valid, no matter how it is raised, it should be marked helpful. Please stop making the life of flaggers miserable because there is some weird quirk in how you handle flags / how the UI present stuff to you / how you can't filter on flags to handle / [invent own reason here].

Comment: Comments are different, @rene - I'm talking about post flags. Edited.

Comment: The same goes for regular flags @Undo. I really want to help you but this whole Q/A really makes me uncomfortable. If you want me to *fix* things I need better reasons. I have yet to see a proper reason why this is needed at all, except for the *mods dislike custom flags*.

Comment: To your broader point, don't miss the forest for the trees. You're right - at the point where I'm looking at an other flag that someone wrote "should be closed" in, there's no harm to me closing the question (and I do). Declining the flag isn't "this wasn't helpful", it's "this wasn't something that needs my attention; put it in the right bucket next time". If someone fires off a big bunch of otherwise helpful flags, I try to decline just enough to trigger a flag warning without a ban. This shouldn't make your life miserable, it should help everyone work within the limitations we have.

Comment: @rene Here's the simplest reason: Review is high volume; moderators are low volume. Review doesn't get to parse out which 'other' flags are actually NAA. Declining these is a nudge in the right direction. I don't think you ever (ab)use other flags like this, so I don't see why you're concerned.

Comment: I'm ranting for those that are less seasoned like I'm @Undo but thanks. I'll give this some thought. I'll reverse the down votes if I think this is helpful. Atm I think it isn't.

Comment: Valid. Goal is to reduce misunderstandings about how we work behind the scenes and maybe head off a few more meta posts, or at least provide a decent reference. This is one of those problems that doesn't show up anywhere else, but SO is... special. We're at 172 flags total, 86% 'other' flags right now (very low dip, it'll be back up at 500-600 within days)

Comment: @rene "*if the flag is valid, no matter how it is raised, it should be marked helpful*" what of the validity of declining a flag raised with the incorrect option? Accepting custom flags when it should have been another option is telling people it's ok, and they'll do it again. Another time a different mod might decline, and then a meta post occurs asking why etc. It's just a waste of people's time across the board. If declined, then next time they'll use the correct flag option and it'll be closed more quickly by community and leave mods' precious time for things community cannot do.

Comment: @James There's no guarantee that either strategy will work. If a flag is declined, how likely is the originator to think about *why* it was declined long enough to figure it out? They're equally likely to assume the post was on-topic, when, really, it was just flagged incorrectly.

Comment: @James so you're saying that I take the effort to provide a mod with extra context to make their life easier and then it gets declined because the same could be achieved with a standard flag? I raise a custom flag to purge comments and will be declined because separate comment flags could have been used? My flags are valid, mark them helpful. Declining my custom flag which I put way more effort in then a standard flag is just rude, not nice, not appreciated and I'll not stop ranting until this weird approach is stopped.

Comment: @rene your flag is not valid, you used the wrong option. Arguably you could use the custom flag for *all* flagging requirements. At what *total flags raised incorrectly* do you draw the line and start declining? Is the answer mathematical, or sensible, or personal opinion? Gotta be a line drawn.

Comment: @rene "*I raise a custom flag to purge comments and will be declined because separate comment flags could have been used?*" it's already been stated that is helpful and so the lot will be cleaned up

Comment: Whoa there. @rene, you're misinterpreting. This isn't about "I raised an other flag with additional information beyond a standard flag", this is about flags that say, literally, and in their entirety, "this is not an answer", "this should be closed", or "low quality". Flags that provide *no* value over a standard flag, other than showing up in a high priority queue.

Comment: @jpaugh I agree that there's no guarantee, but is that really an argument to choose a known wrong option over one that is correct and *has* a chance of doing some good? I have a lock on my front door. The chance of someone trying the door is very slim. And burglars will not bother and likely opt for a darker corner somewhere and hack open a window or whatever. And it hinders me coming and going slightly. Yet I have a lock on my door...because it's the better option

Comment: @Undo I guess I'm going to find out if it will be that clear cut but fair enough. I'll rest my case, rant is over ... and out ...

Comment: Also, it's not like this is new. We've been doing this since forever; if you haven't noticed yet you probably won't.

Answer (score 26):

Moderators are the [exception handlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/310756) on the site. We're here to enforce the guidelines set down over the past decade by the community and the [community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do).

When flagging, it's important to limit moderator flags for issues that are not covered by other standard flag reasons.

There's two reasons for this:

- Standard flags, when applicable, are handled more efficiently; and
- Unnecessary use of custom flags costs moderator time that could be used elsewhere.

## The standard flags are cleared more quickly

The community has moderation privileges and tools that can be used to form a workflow to take care of content on the site. The results of posting many poor posts will result in posts bans. Too many flagged rude comments, or post deletions will raise an automatic mod flag. When it comes to posts, the content is usually moderated by the community.

It's best to keep in mind, the mods don't often clear the mod flag queue on the site. As soon as it starts to go down, more flags appear, so favour the inbuilt mod tools for users before going to the mods to increase the workflow on the site. It will achieve your desired results more quickly.

### Don't custom mod flag for when a standard flag can be used

[How standard are flags handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203217/310756).

> **Spam** and **Offensive** can be automatically handled without moderator
> intervention at six flags, but are only visible to moderators in the
> flags queue.
>
> **Recommend Closure** flags (off-topic, unclear, et al) always go to the
> Close Votes queue (which requires 3k) and are always handled
> automatically. Moderators do not see them in the flags queue.
> .../...
>
> **Not an Answer** flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue.
> They are automatically dismissed if the answer gets deleted at any
> point, but otherwise require a moderator to dismiss. Most of these
> flags are handled in the Low Quality Posts queue without moderator
> intervention.
>
> **Very Low Quality** flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue
> (which requires 2k) after being active for 15 minutes. They are
> generally auto-dismissed by community actions.

With the exception of the **No Longer Needed** comment flag, all other standard flags can be handled by the community without moderator intervention. Many flags will bump a post into a review queue, where reviewers can vote to have the post closed or deleted.

Note that in the "exceptional" cases below, you should **clearly explain why the exception applies in your case** - failing to do so may cause your flag to be declined.

## Posts

#### Abuse and Spam

[Spam and rude/abusive flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327636/3956566) on ***posts*** or ***comments*** can be handled by the community. 6 such flags will automatically delete a post or comment. These flags also cast an automatic downvote on a post, meaning that these flags will quickly remove content from the home page.

#### Answering own question

Answering one's own question is not only allowed, but it's even [encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow). Please don't flag this behaviour.

#### Bad stuff in posts? Edit it out

If there's an unsafe or deprecated link in a post, or someone has posted an answer in a question, make an edit or a suggested edit taking out the offending content, making clear in the edit reason why you've done this. It does not require a mod flag. If you think a user is doing something malicious, then explain that in the flag.

#### Closing posts - unless exceptional

Close flags bump posts into the [close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19847035), where they can be closed by reviewers.

Note that normal users cannot close questions as duplicates of questions with no upvoted answers, unless they were both posted by the same user. This is so that post authors are only directed to posts with answers. If you have a good reason for closing a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question posted by someone else, flag for moderator attention.

Also, posts with active bounties cannot be closed by the community - the bounty needs to be removed by a moderator before it can be closed. In that case, flag for moderator attention.

#### Copying other answers

It's [ok to copy other answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251398/3956566), as long as there's attribution.

If there's a post with several answers and one is copying another one, only flag it if it's a complete duplicate or offers no attribution to the original author. ***If the answer is adding any new detail*** not contained in the other answers, then it's not useless, so don't flag it.

When the question has more than a few answers on it and you think a user is copying another answer, provide a link to the other answer. When flagging posts with dozens of answers, it doesn't help to say the one above, it depends how we sort our answers. Include a link, it's not feasible to scroll through dozens of answers to find the duplicated content.

Many ***code snippets*** may appear similar, as are instructions on using IDEs. Often these are commonly used snippets, that are not subject to ownership. For example how to use a loop. Remember if a new answer looks similar to existing answers, but *does bring any new detail*, it's actually adding more information and unlikely to be deleted.

Before flagging that another user has copied another answer, ***check the time stamps***. It's not unusual for people to write answers at the same time and post them within minutes or even seconds of each other. This is not copying, it's both answering the same question, about the same code, at the same time.

#### Low quality posts

Low quality and not an answer flags bump both questions and answers into the [low quality posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19846408), where they can be deleted by reviewers.

#### Merging questions

Unless two questions are exact duplicates, asking the exact same thing, mods are reluctant to merge questions. If a user has posted the exact question more than once and both questions have answers, then please flag for a question merger.

#### Migrating posts - Unless exceptional

[Migrating posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/310756) requires a mod flag. Users must be mindful in understanding what is on scope for the target site. It has been [made clear by the other sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269283/3956566), they don't want us migrating poor quality content onto their sites.

Mods can only migrate questions that are less than 60 days old. So don't flag to migrate older content.

Unless you're very familiar with the target site's scope, it's unwise to flag for migration and better to flag or vote to close, if a post is off topic. More often than not migration requests are declined. Unless a user with high rep on the target site flags for migration, the mods need to [ask the other site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44836380#44836380) if they'd like to accept the question, if the post looks like it may be on topic for that site. More often than not, the post is rejected, and it's time consuming. So these flags tend to accumulate.

Also, being on topic elsewhere does not necessarily make a post off topic on this site. Sometimes the same question may be on topic for several sites (but should [only be posted on one site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/310756)).

Also see [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers).

#### Posting the same question repeatedly (multiple users)

Reposts under multiple accounts often are no more than a naive, uninformed attempt at gaming the system. In such cases, downvotes, close votes, and possibly a comment warning that the repost is out of order can suffice to curb the nuisance. Still, toying with multiple accounts is sometimes associated with further problematic behaviour, such as voting fraud or ban evasion, so it is fine to cast a custom flag so that a mod can have a look at it. (And of course, if warnings or other measures by the community are not enough to stop the reposts, calling the mods for help is the natural next step.) As usual, explain the concerns in the flag text, and add links to other relevant posts.

#### Posting the same question repeatedly (single user)

If a user continues to post the same question repeatedly, keep flagging them as duplicates. Closure, downvotes and deletions of these questions may result in the user getting an automatic question ban. So the system is built to take care of these issues.

#### Reopening posts

[Editing the body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/310756) of a question within 5 days of it being closed will automatically bump it into the [reopen vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). Greater 3K users can [vote to reopen posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). The author of a question can vote to reopen their [own post with > 250 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/310756).

#### Serial downvoting

If you're being serially downvoted, the automated script should catch it,  so wait 24 hours before flagging. If it isn't caught, then flag.

#### Wrong answers

If you see an answer that provides a non-working solution or makes false claims, downvote it or leave a comment pointing out what's incorrect. If it's a minor and accidental issue, you can also edit the answer to fix it yourself.

Please do not flag answers for being incorrect - those processing the flag don't necessarily know anything about the question, so wouldn't be able to tell whether or not the answer is correct.

## Comments

Think of the workflow. If you can create one custom comment flag asking for a comment thread clean up, rather than flag 30 comments individually, it saves time for both the flagger and the mod (the mods will see all the comment flags). Either way, a no longer needed flag on a comment that is no longer needed is helpful.

We also see any rude/abusive flags that are not deleted by the community. [Consider the merit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368072/comments-asking-for-clarification-or-an-mcve-are-not-rude-abusive) when raising rude/abusive flags on comments.

Moderators can edit comments, and you can flag for moderator attention if a typo or simple mistake is actively causing confusion and harm (e.g. sparking off-topic discussion further along). You shouldn't bother moderators with mistakes that aren't actively harmful.

## Mod issues

There are many issues that cannot be managed within the standard flagging system, for example, post disassociation or serial down voting that's not reversed. People may need to contact the mods for such issues, and that's fine. Always flag if there's a serious issue on the site that you need assistance with.

Serious moderation flags can take some time to handle, and the mods are ok with this. By clearing out some of the unwarranted mod flags, the mods will have more time to fix the things they're supposed to fix.

Note that some things that require moderator action, such as obvious rudeness or obvious spam, should *not* be flagged for moderator attention, but flagged with the built-in *rude or abusive* or *spam* flag. That way, the flag gets handled faster, and other automated actions can occur (such as automated removal if it gets flagged multiple times, and automated downvotes for spam flags). You can, however, use a custom flag if you think the moderator might not recognize it as spam without an explanation.

Comment: While I appreciate the attempt at clarification, the problem is that, at present, there is a non-trivial divergence between what the community thinks is "VLQ" or "NAA", and what our community-driven, exception handlers agree with. There have been a lot of questions about this, to the point where the community advice is basically "never use these flags; just use custom ones".

Comment: @NicolBolas they will be declined. It's not useful to raise a custom mod flag on low quality or NAA posts, they will be declined. I actually think the site's policy on what is NAA is not helpful. I'd rather delete them all. But I'm tied by the current practices. Removing low quality junk answers is hard, because what many people see as poor answers, by definition by the site, they're an answer, so just downvote it.

Comment: On the topic of (non-)suspicious activity: a while ago, I custom flagged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820092 with "Triple post of the same problematic question under different accounts in less than 24 hours. Cf. [links to the other posts]". Would that be an example of a flag of dubious usefulness?

Comment: @duplode well, they looked like poor quality posts and possibly (I don't know this for sure) they were circumventing a post ban by opening a separate account. If the questions are on topic, usually it's better just to delete them. Unless you suspect voting fraud. The point I'm trying to make is, it's ok to have multiple accounts. If all the user is doing is posting duplicated questions, they need to be closed, and of course if they continue to do it after being told to stop by the community, by all means raise a flag.

Comment: @YvetteColomb My usual course of action on seeing obvious multiple account reposts is to give the user a stern warning in a comment -- in this case, other folks already had done so on the earlier posts. That being so, I gather that, given the persistence in the face of warnings (it was actually the *fourth* post -- I had missed one of them), the flag was appropriate.

Comment: @duplode yes I think so. I think I've come across as too harsh lined. Please feel free to edit these things in. I'm not the owner or definitive guide. Just trying to tweak it, so we have somewhere to refer to that's on hand and relatable.

Comment: I may be reading over it, but I think I'm missing legal issues. "We're not lawyers", etc. etc. Similarly questions of a potentially nefarious reason such as questions about creating a virus. When one appears you can be certain it appears on meta too asking about reporting it.

Comment: @Gimby please feel free to edit and add things you think are missing

Comment: As is, this answer is ___way too long___. The users that _need_ to read this aren't going to.

Comment: This answer comes 10 years into the site's existence. Does SO management not see that the have a problem with skills identifying & communicating site goals & protocols?

Comment: @Cerbrus it's in alphabetical order and shouldn't be too hard to skim through. Particularly if it ends up in the FAQ.

Comment: @Rob I have added a slimmed down version of the section you have removed, under the header "Posting the same question repeatedly (multiple users)". Pinging you so you can have a look at it.

Comment: @duplode Personally, those cases are actually fine to flag. Originally, this answer asked not to flag these cases as *usually* these flags don't lead anywhere. However, whether or not the flags pan out isn't something a user can predict. I've caught quite a few ban evaders/sockpuppets due to these types of flags. It only takes us a minute to determine whether or not something fishy is going on. I'd prefer to keep it simple for the users. If it looks suspicious - flag it.

Comment: @Rob I have had a final go at tweaking that passage, trying to make it less prescriptive, in line with what you have said.

Comment: `With the exception of the No Longer Needed comment flag, all other standard flags can be handled by the community without moderator intervention.` AFAIK this is incorrect, after getting a certain number of NLN flags (I think it starts at 3 and increases with the comment's score), the comment is automatically removed.

Comment: @YvetteColomb If you have some time, can you validate the edits that were made just now? I'm not totally sure they're really good advice.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier anyone can edit and review and refine those edits. It's not "my" post being a CW. I will have a read, but also feel free to edit it.