# What should happen with this mess?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

Here is the situation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675706/c-editing-codes-for-vector-scaling (edit: post has been deleted) got downvoted, but as it had answers, the OP couldn't delete it. The OP decided to delete the text instead, leaving a useless message as a question, with two zero-score answers.

[image]

The question could be rolled back, but it should have been closed as too broad in the beginning, and as a <2k user I would run the risk of the edit being rejected.

As it is, it is VLQ, but can't be flagged as such because it is too old. Would flagging as too broad or off-topic help in any way?

How should this be handled?

Comment: In future you can rollback edits, granted they go into a review queue, just make sure your edit comment mentions you are rollingback, this prompts the edit reviewers so they know what you are doing. I am below 2k but have had rollback edits approved, just leave a comment like *"Rollback to revision x, after OP defaced the question"*

Comment: You can always come into the SO-CVR chatroom and request a rollback, if you don't want to put a rollback into the review queue.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @halfer! On the chat room, hmm... I've never been to chat. Is SO-CVR strictly about close votes? Maybe I should have a look-in sometime.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ: no probs. CVs is its primary reason, but like most chatrooms we chat about all sorts of stuff, it's pretty friendly. There's a [few rules](http://socvr.org/) but nothing too onerous.

Comment: "What should happen with this mess?" I just love that title (and also the depressing situation you're describing). I just saves my day, I just keep returning to the question to read it.

Comment: @Jean: That was really what I was thinking when I was surveying the damage, but I didn't really expect it to be a very catchy title (now it has 2156 views). Its always great to know that someone likes it!

Comment: meta works in strange ways :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Rolling back this question (because it has been defaced) is appropriate. Even if it should be closed, it shouldn't be defaced.

Flagging as too broad is appropriate too. For defaced questions, you should consider the best possible variant of the question when flagging to close it.

Rene has already rolled it back and I've put in a close vote, so now, you need to do nothing at all.

Nowadays, such defacement raises alerts in multiple chatrooms. However, these old questions can go under the radar.

Comment: Would flagging as too broad possibly result in a declined flag, though? Would reviewers check the edit history, or just judge by what they see? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Well, that's something I don't have to worry about :). I'm sure if users saw the defaced variant, they would vote to close too, possibly for a different reason but that doesn't decline/dispute your flag.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ if you're worried that a flag or edit would be declined, you can always try a custom flag. Explain in the flag text: *This post is defaced by the OP and should be rolled-back but I don't have full edit privileges so my suggested edit would probably be declined. When rolled back the question will be too broad but flagging it in its current state might take the close vote reviewers off-guard. Can you use your powers to rectify this unwanted state the question is in*. Do know mods are bit more strict on custom flags: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693 so make sure it's worthwhile.

Comment: I thought about that, but decided that the post should be clear enough to be handled by the community, without wasting the mods' time.