# The Return of "What should happen with this mess"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

This question & answer [C - Define type that is always 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891312/c-define-type-that-is-always-32-bit) was first asked in a very broad way.

So the classic answer was "use `stdint.h`", and it's an obvious duplicate. Someone answered and got 7 (!) upvotes for this before (and after it was closed).

Now OP edited the question, and asks the same thing but *without using any includes*:

> Many people suggest solution:
>
> ```
>    #include <stdint.h>
>
>    int32_t my_32bit_int;
> ```
>
> as it was already the answer to similar question. However this is not the answer - what is "int32_t" how can we guarantee that it is 32 bit wide? What I try to acomplish is to define such 32 bit type using plain C keyword with no dependecy on other libraries etc.

Now I can't figure out what to do:

- *leave closed*: but the question is *not* a duplicate anymore, OP edited it, adding new constraints, changing the question.
- *rollback the question edit and leave closed*: logical, but not very nice & OP will probably rollback again
- *reopen*: okay, but there's a highly upvoted answer which will send a wrong message to future readers & answerers
- *downvote the answer like hell and delete it*: logical, but does answerer deserve that? I don't think so
- *edit the answer so it answers*: not possible without changing it completely (and frankly I don't have a clue about what to answer :))
- *delete the whole thing*: and let OP ask a clearer question. The answer wouldn't get in the way of new answers. Not very nice
- something else? flag it for mods? but how to explain?

(Title lifted from [What should happen with this mess?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369318/what-should-happen-with-this-mess), just because I dig it, but a different case.)

Comment: Well, if I had the mod power, I would remove the dupe link, roll it back and close it as unclear, which it was, originally,... maybe?  I hate it when multiple cockups make things so difficult:(

Comment: I could do half the way: reopen... but can't close again... well, nice alternative.

Comment: The new question is just too broad, so it's not like the question should actually be open.  Your meta question is effectively asking what you should do if a question was edited such that a different close reason is now applicable.  Some people say it's not worth it to bother reopening a question just to re-close it.  Others thing it is.  If you do think it's important, I'd advice trying to get a mod who can just unilaterally reopen and then reclose it, rather than 10 people to vote to reopen/reclose.

Comment: 2 comments indicating the same thing. Looks like it answers.

Comment: The general consensus is question edits which invalidate already existing answers should be rolled back by any user with edit privileges. If the asker wants to ask a new question, then they can ask a *new* question. There's a grey area when a question is so unclear that you get >1 answer approaching the question from different interpretations. In such case, the people giving answers shouldn't have done so until the question was clarified. Clarifying the question in those cases is desirable, and the Q editor should leave a comment on the answer that misunderstood the Q to notify of the change.

Comment: The reason `stdint.h` exists is **there is no standard way** to do it. In fact, `stdint.h` **is** the standard way. Using some homebrew crap is bad enough. Worse if others are bothered with that. Folks should just write clean and understandable code. Any C programmer not knowing `int32_t` et al. is not a C progammer. In reverse: every C programmer understands this and the implications (2's complement, no padding-bits, etc)

Comment: The title reads like some 50ies Jack Arnold B-movie: "Return of the swamp monster". Guess the association is quite fitting.

Comment: It is yet another example how experts in the [c] tag completely fail to explain anything to a newbie.   Not so sure what the mental block might be, perhaps they've been doing it for far too long and can't remember what it was like when they were a newbie.  And it all turns into a "this is the only way to do it the right way, can't quite remember when I decided that".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all... It's still a duplicate. The fact that the asker doesn't like most of the answers on the original doesn't change the fact that they're asking for pretty much the same thing; there are answers that *should* satisfy their requirements even if they aren't highly-ranked.

If it *wasn't* a duplicate... And *was* still a good question... I'd recommend this:

> - reopen: okay, but there's a highly upvoted answer which will send a wrong message to future readers & answerers

...along with a courtesy comment on the answer informing the author that they've been [chameleoned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).