# I would like a more detailed explanation for why my recent moderator flags were declined

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

Not sure if I could bring mod-flags here, but recently the mod-flag declined messages are literally nothing helpful.

Let's say, "decline" mod-flag is like a punishment (or similar) for getting to know we made a mistake and we learn from the mistake. I have been doing a lot of wrong things in Stack Overflow and there were a lot of mods (I don't wanna name them), who have helped me to be a good citizen of Stack Overflow.

When I give a good explanation of what I feel, the decline reason has been extremely not useful! Some recent examples from the past three days are:

1. The below mod-flag reply says we both were pulling from the question material. I am not sure what it means. Technically, the copy of the answer is posted after 2 mins 6 seconds after I posted the answer. The answer copied a part of my answer and got a vote too. So technically, the contents of the copied answer is a substring of my answer! When I raised a mod-flag, I got this response yesterday (after 3 days), which doesn't help me how I should improve or what's the problem with this mod-flag. [[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65318341)]
   [image: mod-flag-dont-understand]
2. As my old mod-flag wasn't clear, I wanted to clarify what was wrong, but well, this is another decline leading to temp flag ban and doesn't help much. Also, the post was up when I flagged and it was later gone when the mod reviewed my flag, now got the flag declined. [[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64740960)]
   [image: mod-flag-double-decline]

I don't want the mods to expose themselves in these two incidents, but it would be really helpful if you can provide a better response and frequent declining of mod-flags (we understand the stress mods go through and appreciate the busy schedule) can be reduced so that we can also do something confidently.

Just my thoughts, so tagged with discussion and support.

Comment: Without reading what the flag said, both response seemed reasonable. What are you expecting to happen? On the 1st: the reasoning is solid. Both post referenced the same thing and ended with kindasorta the same answer. That's OK. 2nd and 3rd: it seems that you were vague first and later the outcome was achieved via other means, what different outcome you expected?

Comment: @Braiam **First flag:** I really didn't understand what the mod meant by "two of you were pulling from the question material to answer". I thought we should answer the question, not some random code-base or pseudo code, right? How should we tackle people who copy paste after a good answer (or problem solving) answer and claim it as theirs? **Second flag:** Agreed with the response, but could have made as disputed or helpful, not declined, counting towards flag ban. Don't you think?

Comment: *"Let's say, "decline" mod-flag is like a punishment"* - Let's not...because it isn't. It just a notice that the mod disagreed with your assessment.

Comment: Relevant: [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693/11682469)

Comment: In the first case, the fact that the other answer used the same alt text as you, which wasn't present in the question, is pretty damning IMHO

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks, this is exactly what I said. The other answerer copied my answer. And this is the reason of my mod-flag. It's so bad that I don't know to frame right words. I have to work on my communication skills! 

Comment: @Braiam See the above comment by tgdavies... Now you would understand or agree... 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Not sure if I could bring mod-flags here…

Sure, that's fine. Moderators have to keep flags confidential, but you can choose to reveal details about your own flags, if you want.

> Let's say, "decline" mod-flag is like a punishment (or similar) for getting to know we made a mistake and we learn from the mistake.

While it's great to learn from declined flags, having a flag declined is ***not*** a punishment. All it means is that a moderator disagreed with you: they looked at your flag and felt that no action needed to be taken. Please don't take them personally.

> When I give a good explanation of what I feel, the decline reason has been extremely not useful!

We should probably try to do better in providing clear flag decline reasons, but…

- SO moderators handle *lots* of flags per day, so
- Most of the time, we just choose from one of the standard decline reasons, and
- Even when we do decide to type out a custom message, we hit an *extremely* small character limit for these messages.

> The below mod-flag reply says we both were pulling from the question material. I am not sure what it means.

It means that the moderator who reviewed your flag did not see any abuse there. Your flag was interpreted as a "possible plagiarism" flag—in other words, I think this other user copied my answer, and as such, they should be sanctioned and the answer removed. The moderator who handled your flag looked at the date-time stamp and determined that, based on how closely in time the answers were posted, there was no evidence of plagiarism or copying. Furthermore, they noted that most of the common elements in the code blocks were pulled from the example code in the question, which explains why they were common across the two answers. They didn't think that the commonalities were indicative of the other answerer copying from your answer.

That is…way too much to put into a flag decline message. Perhaps we should have said:

> No evidence of plagiarism or inappropriate behavior. The answers were posted only 2 minutes apart, and similar elements are derived from the question.

That would *probably* fit in the character limit. I don't know if it would be any more clear to you. But extremely concise writing is *very* time-consuming and challenging, so we probably aren't going to start taking this much care for each individual flag. Sorry.

> As my old mod-flag wasn't clear, I wanted to clarify what was wrong…

While it's OK to raise another flag in order to clarify, you have to be very careful, because it often comes across as simply, "I want another bite at the apple". In other words: it often comes across as, "I know you declined the previous flag, but I disagree, so I'm going to run this through again, this time with more insistence." Fairly or not, we mods tend to find that kind of annoying.

Regarding your flag message here, you state:

> Can my previou flag be made helpful or dismissed?

It was. It was marked as "declined". That's how flags work. Moderators can only choose from two options when handling custom flags: helpful or declined. We will decline a flag if we do not feel that any action is warranted. There's no "dismissed" outcome for custom post flags. And, as the response says, even if there *were*, we can't go back in time to change flag outcomes.

Furthermore, as the decline message stated, you just need to be more clear in future flags. In fact, reading your second flag, it seems that your first flag was completely incorrect. The first flag says that the answer is an "exact copy" of your answer, whereas your second flag says that the answer is "a copy paste of the content of the question". How can it be both?

If you're flagging an answer as being useless because it simply copies non-working code from the question, then *say that*. Don't rely on moderators to read your mind or figure out what you meant through context.

Comment: Thanks for such an awesome answer. Would love to agree with everything. Except, the two flags where for different answers.  They're not for the same post. I got what I needed from your detailed response. You're always super helpful!