# Why are some of my flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer, flag-history

I got access to the review queues and also learnt about the page where you can see all your flags (/users/flag-summary/).

I could see there some of my flags are declined, but I really cannot understand why. Here is a list of some declined flags:

- [Flagged as "Self answered within 4 comments."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283281/my-search-is-not-giving-proper-results-whenever-i-search-for-user-it-is-returnin) ; has been denied for **flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention**

  - I flagged this as it's not a useful question at all, and the author answered themselves within 4 comments.
- [Flagged this answer as "Not an Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276420/write-bold-text-to-file/66276518#66276518) ; has been denied for **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**

  - This answer doesn't answer the question, plus it is only code, without any explanation
- [Flagged this answer as "Not an Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276332/python-attributeerror-partially-initialized-module/66276366#66276366) ; has been denied for **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**

  - This answer is copy-pasta from the question code, they just changed a `_` to a `.`, but the answer is worse, as code proposed doesn't even exist.

I hope you will be able to explain those declined flags to me, so I can understand the denial reasons.

Comment: *"Self answered within 4 comments."* is certainly funny but not a great close reason.

Comment: See also: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/348196)

Comment: @JeanneDark Yes, this did answer my questions for the last 2, thanks

Comment: Regarding your first flag, what exactly did you want a mod to do (close the question? delete the comments?) and why?

Comment: [If you think a question is not useful, you can downvote it](https://i.imgur.com/0QnMqzO.png). If you think the question should be closed, you may flag it but you should select one of the closure reasons presented to you in the flag dialog. Custom flags (moderator intervention) should only be used when seeking actions that regular users (even with high privileges) can't take and a moderator needs to step in.

Comment: @JeanneDark I expected the comments to be deleted and the question to be edited/an answer to be added (by the user) as they are adding more infos / answering within comments

Comment: @41686d6564 I see what you mean, but in that case there was not really an appropriate closure reason. What one should I have selected?

Comment: Then why do you flag for a moderator when you expect an edit and an answer the other user?

Comment: When there isn't an appropriate close reason, then that is a strong indicator that the question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: the problem is that is your subjected opionion and the mods can have their own opinion, now you have to learn, what is possible, all you get , is a hint what to do.

Comment: @Gogu72 - If a question is caused by a typo then you should vote to close for that reason.  If you expect it to be edited and answered then you could certainly do both those actions yourself.  However, I suspect you don’t want to answer questions caused by a typo, for the same reason many don’t want to do that.  As for the reason?  “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo” - is a perfect reason for at least one of those questions.

Comment: I'm coming back here as the first flag (answered within 4 comments) was declined as said in my question, and now I see the question has been deleted... Then why is my flag declined if the question is deleted some hours after???

Comment: Note that the question was deleted by its author, not by a moderator. It can also happen that a mod takes action and still declines your flag to make you aware of your wrong usage of them.

Comment: @JeanneDark Ah ok. But if the question is deleted, then my flag has been used correctly, no? (not in that case, I mean if the question was deleted by moderator)

Comment: No, the author merely decided to delete their own question for some reason and the system allowed them to. In my experience, deleting a post doesn't mark custom flags automatically helpful so the sequence of events also didn't matter. And I guess it would have been declined no matter what to teach you how to use them correctly. Here's some guidance on when and how to custom flag: [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693/11682469) and [chat messages by a mod](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51411130#51411130).

Answer (score 1):

This is just my personal opinion, I have not reviewed any of these flags.

---

> - [Flagged as "Self answered within 4 comments."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283281/my-search-is-not-giving-proper-results-whenever-i-search-for-user-it-is-returnin) ; has been denied for **flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention**
>
>   - I flagged this as it's not a useful question at all, and the author answered themselves within 4 comments.

You raised a custom-mod-flag. There is another way to properly flag questions that are

> resolved in a way less likely to help future readers

This flag can be found under `needs improvement`>`A community-specific reason`>`Not reproduceable or was caused by a typo`

> - [Flagged this answer as "Not an Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276420/write-bold-text-to-file/66276518#66276518) ; has been denied for **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**
>
>   - This answer doesn't answer the question, plus it is only code, without any explanation

The not an answer flag should be used in cases described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/10871900)

> - [Flagged this answer as "Not an Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276332/python-attributeerror-partially-initialized-module/66276366#66276366) ; has been denied for **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**
>
>   - This answer is copy-pasta from the question code, they just changed a `_` to a `.`, but the answer is worse, as code proposed doesn't even exist.

[Same here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/10871900)