# Knowing when to flag, and knowing when I am being overly critical

Tags: discussion

Last night, or yesterday (depending on where you at), [I flagged a question, and an answer. I also downvoted both.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552964/is-the-jsconfig-json-file-required-to-be-used-in-every-javascript-project?noredirect=1#comment126466344_71552964) The original question, head & body, was as follows:

> ##### *Should the jsconfig.json file be used in every JavaScript project?*
>
> *Will adding the jsconfig.json file make the development process easier
> should I use a "jsconfig.json" file for every project?*

Using a comment, I claimed that the question was opinionated, as I couldn't think of an answer that wouldn't be opinionated. I flagged the question as such (using the opinionated option).

Below the question was an answer already, and it was made by the author  (You can view the link to read it), but it did not attempt to answer the question, it only documented how to use a `jsconfig.json` file. At this point it seemed to me that the person was just trying to get reputation w/o any respect, or care, for the rules that regulate Stack Overflow and keep it a useful & healthy resource for programmers.

I commented that it didn't attempt to answer the question. During this time I noticed that the question was ranked above other questions with the same tag that had been created more recently. I also noticed the author was editing his question in meaningless ways to keep the question afloat. I flagged and asked for moderator intervention, as it didn't seem like something I could do anything about at the time.

---

I checked back on the question some minutes later, and I found that the author changed the question's title (but not the body) to this:

> ##### "Is the jsconfig.json file required to be used in every JavaScript project?"

This time I commented that this isn't a reproducible problem, and it's a silly thing to ask because there's no reason anyone would ever think.

This morning I checked back to see what happened with the flag, and found that my flags were declined with the reason for declining being:

> "Only flag questions in need of moderator intervention".

---

I am not really sure what to make of this whole situation. I don't flag often, usually I only flag when something is quite obviously not up to par with Stack Overflow standards, or a person's behavior is precarious. In the past I rarely had flags declined, but lately my flags seem to be declined quite often. The part that bothers me the most though is that I don't know what I could have done better. They use to always give a clear reason as to why the flag didn't need a moderator, instead of just saying that it didn't.

I was hoping the community could help me out, and maybe let me know, what went wrong here, what could I have done better? Was I being overly critical of this question & answer?

Comment: What kind of flag did you use? Was it a custom moderator flag? Did you flag both question and answer? If so, which kind of flag did you use on each post?

Comment: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1426539)

Comment: [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693/1426539)

Comment: Your flag addressed two concerns: the answer being technically wrong, and the OP making an abusive amount of edits. (obligatory disclaimer for everyone else, my interpretation of the flag text, which was relatively short and basically made that point). An answer being technically wrong is not a flag reason, and there was no evidence of abusive editing, so yes, it was declined. Moreover, you only have a single declined flag on that post. Your previous decline was in September, or a solid 6 ish months ago. There's nothing here that requires mod intervention; could've been solved with downvotes,

Comment: and possibly close votes, but neither of those concerns were presented in the flag, so you got that decline reason instead of the "use standard flags" reason. For the record, bumping edits require a _lot_ more than a total of three edits; multiply by 5 in the same time span, and you would've had more of a foundation for a flag on that front

Comment: "This time I commented that this isn't a reproducible problem, and it's a silly thing to ask because there's no reason anyone would ever think." I'm not quite following what you mean by this. SO isn't just for debugging, so it's okay to have a question *without* a problem that needs reproducing. Without subject matter expertise, it's not clear to me why no one should ever think that – packaging is hard and "do I need this common file" is a regular point of confusion for the languages I work with.

Comment: For the record, the question seems to be badly phrased but has useful Q&A pair at its core. It would revolve more around "What is a jsconfig.json file and how is it used" then the answer OP gave would be more on point and definitely useful as an explanation about the file. Whether or not it *should* be used is indeed opinion-based but *how* it is used can help people to answer it for themselves.

Comment: simply downvote it, that encourages more people to downvote and it goes away

Answer (score 13):

There are different types of flags and you should endeavor to use the proper ones. I think the core issue here was that you used a moderator attention flag instead of using a standard Not an answer flag.

For the question, you flagged as opinion-based, which put the question in the close review queue. That wasn't declined but the asker opted to also use the same close reason to vote their question closed, which marked your flag as helpful.

Here's the text of your flag on the answer :

> Not only does this not answer the question, but this guy keeps editing the question in an attempt to keep the question at the top of the list. He's acting like a goofball, and his/her behavior is a bit precarious.

This can be broken up into two parts - the first part of that is a simple NAA flag - it's a flag that goes into the low quality posts review queue so that either users or moderators can handle it. But only an actual NAA flag will go into that queue.

The second part is an assertion that the user is intentionally editing to bump the question - but the question was only edited twice. There may be other interim edits within the 5-minute grace period but that's not generally concerning, so two edits doesn't seem worthy of a mod attention flag - I usually start getting worried when it's more like 6-8 in a short period and none of the edits add anything of value - they're just rearranging text in minor ways.

So, that gets you down to just an NAA flag which would just be a standard flag - so use that if you truly think the answer isn't an answer.

Custom moderator flags are often quite taxing to handle as they can be about anything. Endeavoring to only use them when absolutely necessary is important for any flagger. I don't think it was necessary in this case. Please don't see this as a reason to not flag - flagging is an important and integral part of our system - but help the mods out a bit by making it easier to categorize those flags by putting them in the correct bins.

Comment: I knew it was an issue on my part, and I was hopping that a moderator would critique me in a way that would help me understand what I did wrong, and what I could do differntly in the future. I want to have a possitive, and helpful, impact on _Stack Overflow_. I really love this site. I really appriciate this answer, as it puts the entire situation into perspective for me. The perspective of someone who is an obvious expert on the matter. Your an exceptional Moderator (for what it's worth, I've read some of your other answers & they were all just as exceptional as this one).

Comment: What would have been flag-worthy is the text on the poster's profile: "Hello, I'm Arnav Thorat, and **I'm 12 years old**!"