# When a moderator is suspended, can the question closed by him/her be considered reopened again?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

A specific example, *[REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)*. This question has 347 upvotes so far, but it was closed by a moderator. Now his account is suspended (the suspension period ends on Aug 5, 2024 at 15:39).

So can the question like this to be reopened?

For this particular question I agree it was opinion based but I was asking a general question that if the moderator is suspended for such a long time I guess he/she must have done something quite inappropriately, so can we trust the decision he/she made
(solely by him) before?

If you never experience the frustration of a question been closed or even deleted you probably will think my question is silly. But the frustration exists and is quite real, just google it, e.g. [It’s time for Stack Overflow to address its moderation problems](https://medium.com/codex/its-time-for-stack-overflow-to-address-its-moderation-problems-6111e45b6e94) or [And They Closed a Valid Question on Stack Overflow Again](https://yihui.org/en/2018/02/closed-so-question/)

I got a comment "If all this is a subtle way to discredit moderators", which I need to make it very clear, "No, not at all." That is *not* my purpose.

#### Update

I got some comments saying I used a bad example to show my point. So let me use another example: *[Why should I practice Test Driven Development and how should I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303/why-should-i-practice-test-driven-development-and-how-should-i-start)* or *[Why should I unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304411/why-should-i-unit-test)*

I am quite sure that the question like "why should I practice ..." is mostly opinion based, so why weren't they closed?

I can find more examples like that to illustrate my point, which is sometimes questions are closed/deleted too quickly. Whether they should be closed or not is totally up to a single person's decision and sometimes it is hard to judge whether a question is opinion based on not. But when I first asked the question I just happened to find *[REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)*. I emphasized it was closed by a suspended moderator, which side-tracked my question. I apologize for that.

Comment: Why should it be reopened? Seems POB regardless of who closed it and what the status of their account is currently.

Comment: Moderator status is irrelevant, but the question is also currently locked, so you need to convince another moderator that the question is worthy to be unlocked *and* reopened.

Comment: @Qiulang I looked at the question with my eyes and saw it's POB. Therefore, I trust the decision to close it as POB. You seem to imply we shouldn't trust this decision, though. Why? What makes the question on-topic so that it requires reopening? Because surely you cannot solely base that on the account status of the closer. There is no real correlation there. If the user was suspeneded for closing this one question, then I'd expect staff would have also reopened the question, as well.

Comment: Again, I verified this decision is correct. What are you suggesting - undoing it *even though it's correct*? Your question cannot really have a blanket answer and I'm apprehensive why you're trying to push for one.

Comment: @Qiulang the big question is: *if the suspension is related to moderation at all*, and thus the actions need to be undone. It has happened on other SE sites, but not on this particular user.

Comment: @Qiulang yet you used it as an example. For the purpose of a blanket policy on reversing a suspended moderator's decisions. I really don't get the question, then - "Here is a question closed correctly but the account which closed it was suspended. Can this be reopened?" seems like a non-sequetur. What answer other than "No, it's correctly closed" did you expect?

Comment: @Qiulang ...I don't know what you're fishing for. The question was unilaterally closed by the moderator. And the decision is correct - I verified it, you also say you agree. So, should *every* decision be reversed? You literally gave the example to counter it. Can *every* decision be trusted? No, but that doesn't really change with suspension.  You can disagree with any current moderator action *right now* - flag, or vote, or contact the site. Or you can even ping them in a comment to explain why you think it's wrong. I've had success with that approach.

Comment: So I guess you never experience the frustration of a question been closed or even deleted. Lucky for you but the frustration exists and is real, just google it. I quote an article here [It’s time for Stack Overflow to address its moderation problems](https://medium.com/codex/its-time-for-stack-overflow-to-address-its-moderation-problems-6111e45b6e94)

Comment: "*So I guess you never experience the frustration of a question been closed or even deleted.*" And that's relevant...how? Let me remind you yet again that the question you showcased was correctly closed. And you apparently agreed with this. And now somehow you want to...cure some sort of frustration? Of what, questions that are closed correctly and should be closed correctly? Surely, if you wanted to tackle *incorrectly* closed questions, you could have done that. Not call into question decisions by a suspended account and providing an example clearly showing they should not all be reversed.

Comment: If all this is a subtle way to discredit moderators and call for lowering of quality standards, then...well, not going to happen. If you have any point other than that, feel free to make it.

Comment: @qiulang frustration has many sources. For most people it will be that they do not understand Stack Overflow. That frustration does not form an argument for reopening or undeleting, it needs to be solved in different ways.

Comment: "If all this is a subtle way to discredit moderators " No, not at all. But I see now you and I could never be on the same page. So I will stop.

Comment: "*That is NOT my purpose.*" Your purpose becomes murkier with every update. Again, you agreed that the question you used as example should be closed. And yet you asked if it can be reopened. And more broadly, should all moderator decisions by the closer be reversed. *Again*, your example shows that no - such blanket reversal is unwarranted. You tried to appeal to general fear of this moderator's actions. Which again doesn't make sense. And now somehow you're trying to shoehorn in complaints over closures which is entirely unrelated to the moderator. How is that relevant to the point?

Comment: This question was closed 7 years ago what does this moderator’s recent behavior have to do with the closure?

Comment: And now there is even more meta commentary completely irrelevant to the actions of a moderator. It feels less and less like an innocent question and more and more like a springboard to try and complain. About moderation in general, is what it seems like. This is quite frustrating to me but no - that's not what the question is about, is it?

Comment: If you're asking "can we reconsider actions taken by someone who's since been suspended", then: of course. It doesn't matter whether they're a moderator, although that status does mean their actions can be unilateral more often (see also: gold badge holders). We can reconsider actions taken by people who _haven't been suspended_, even; that's the kind of thing Meta's here for. But that doesn't necessarily mean they'll be reverted and using an example where the action was correct seems somewhat pointless.

Comment: Re-examining every single question that they ever closed seems like a lot of (largely unnecessary) work. If you see a question that they closed improperly, feel free to vote to re-open it.

Comment: Let me say something about the rants you linked to. I get pretty annoyed by people that talk about me but not with me. I'm here on Meta. Post your well thought out arguments as a question and we discuss the matter. Instead the rants get posted elsewhere and then going forward they get thrown at us as "evidence" when ever someone sees fit. We have [closed and/or deleted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1653721) 14 million questions, off course you'll find 20 random people that agree SO moderation is bad. For those we have created reddit.

Comment: My question was closed, got 33 downvotes and quite some aggressive comments so as you can image this is quite an unpleasant experience for me and believe it or not I never planned to antagonize anyone. I just feel sometimes people close/delete a question too quickly, after all doesn't SO always say "be nice".

Comment: @Qiulang and you would be right that sometimes it happens. Maybe even too often. It's all handled by people after all. Millions of them. What also happens too often is that people read too much into comments. You call them aggressive, but it is probably nothing more than perception. The comment system is pretty poor and unorganised, before you know it it will look like people are piling on to you. The "someone is wrong on the internet" effect, so to say. People see something they disagree with, they just have to post their own comment rather than let others handle it.

Comment: @Gimby in my case I don't think I read too much into comments, on the contrary I feel it was others read too much into my question. I even got the comment "If all this is a subtle way to discredit moderators and call for lowering of quality standards, then...well, not going to happen."  which I don't know what to say. But after that I though about deleting my question so to save all the troubles. But seeing I have received quite some comments and 3 answers, deleting my question seems irresponsible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "using an example where the action was correct seems somewhat pointless." I just happened to find that example when I planed to ask my question. I can give a more appropriate example, e.g. [Why should I practice Test Driven Development and how should I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303/why-should-i-practice-test-driven-development-and-how-should-i-start) isn't this question totally opinion based and  should be closed a long time ago?

Comment: Well it was _posted_ a long time ago, site standards have firmed up over time as the network has grown, but also appears to have absolutely nothing to do with the suspension of a moderator so it's not clear how it's an appropriate example for the topic you're asking about.

Comment: Then what about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304411/why-should-i-unit-test  2 years ago ?

Comment: Are we still talking about overriding decisions made by suspended moderators? I get the feeling we're not.

Comment: @F1Krazy you were probably right. My point is sometimes questions are closed/deleted too quickly and it is unfriendly to the questioner. But when I planned to ask my question I happened to find a question was closed (solely) a suspended moderator. To emphasized my point (question was closed too quickly) I mentioned that fact and it sidetracked my point.

Comment: That's another good example of a question where no subsequently-suspended moderator seems to have been involved, which makes it another bad one for your question. What's your point here, what are you actually trying to ask about?

Comment: (POB = [primarily opinion-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420). It *is* in [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353).)

Comment: Today I have another example to show my frustration. I am not sure if my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094448/what-are-the-problems-with-a-flat-node-modules-folder is opinion based or not. But less than 2 minutes I asked I got a close vote and a down vote without any explanation. But to me it is really not opinion based and I really hope someone can answer my question.

Answer (score 28):

Which person closed the question is irrelevant. The only thing that's relevant is if the question should be closed or not.

If a moderator (or any other user) is suspended for incorrectly closing a bunch of questions, we should review those and reopen if appropriate. If they're suspended for any other reason, such as is the case here, we certainly should not reopen questions that should be closed en masse just because they did something the company deems suspension-worthy.

Answer (score 17):

*Can* the actions of a moderator be reversed?

Yes, they can. All actions on the system can be reversed by other users. Some times by regular ones via voting, some times by more privileged users like staff or other moderators.

*Should* the actions of *this specific moderator* be reversed?

Not as a blanket policy. The example question is closed as being opinion-based, which is a correct closure. Therefore, it proves that a blanket reversal of the actions would not be correct in all cases.

Are *maybe* some of their actions when moderating content wrong?

Yes, it is possible. We are all human, we can all make a mistake. Even current moderators might make a wrong decision. The result should be the same - if you identify an action you think is wrong, then you can:

- Edit a post to improve it and potentially remove problems it had. For example, if it was a closed question, then the reason for the closure can be addressed.
- Ping a user in a comment. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)
- Use one of the standard flags on the system. See [What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) and [flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Vote for closure or reopening. See [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)
- Flag for moderator attention and explain what is not covered by any of the above. See [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693)
- Post on Meta.
- Use the [Contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to reach staff.

This is the same regardless of which user did the action. Be they diamond moderators or any other user. Whether their account is active or not.

Answer (score 15):

Whether or not moderator is suspended, is not relevant at all, in this nor in any other case or action.

If there is a problem with particular post and action, then you can bring that post to the Meta for a review. This is a regular procedure. We commonly question even active moderator's actions because they are just human and can make errors in judgement.

What we don't do here, is judge **all actions** by any person, being moderator or not, based on whether they are suspended or whether they have made some *bad* calls in the past or present. And we certainly don't want to automatically revoke any moderation actions as such as this could wreak havoc.